# How to send this type of data in post request in volley?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

This wants to send JsonObject in key Json. So please tell how to send it using volley.
    json={"product":"magie"}

How to send this data in Volley, I have add the asyncTask code below for hit api with that type of data.

```
enter code here

protected void onPreExecute() {
    if (progress)
        GlobalAlerts.showProgressDialog(context);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String resp = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("product","magie");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String data = "json=" + jsonObject.toString(); 
    String url ="http://anc.php";
    resp = new JsonCall().executeHttpPostRequest(url, data);
    return resp;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {
    if (progress)
        GlobalAlerts.hideProgressDialog();
    if (resp != null) {
        callback.onTaskComplete(resp);
    } else {
        GlobalAlerts.singleAlert((Activity) context, context.getString(R.string.warning), "Error", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: please check this https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/ else post your some code here which you done

Comment: You may find your answer in the following link:- [> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873718/how-do-i-make-a-volley-jsonobject-request-with-a-custom-object-as-a-parameter][1]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)

Comment: @Amol Patel plz post what you have tried otherwise search on google. there are many examples for json parser using volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for that is like put data in jsonObject and then pass jsonObject in hashmap with key json.

enter code here

```
    String url = "http://anc.php";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("product", "magie");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final HashMap<String,String> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap2.put("json",jsonObject.toString());

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("order_list", response);
            GlobalAlerts.hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            GlobalAlerts.hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            /*Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("employee_id"," 1");*/
            return hashMap2;
        }
    };
    Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, "order_list");
```